# Is this old house safe?

Tags: safety, construction, old-house

I bought an old house (built 1960) which had been abandoned for the last 30 years.

There was no concrete used in the construction, the base is made of some kind of white stone until about a meter up, which is then followed by solid brick up to the top.

I've got advice from locals that I should demolish it and build a new one using the existing plans (which is common practice where I live), but looking at it, it seems pretty sturdy. All of the wooden construction, between the floors and on the roof, although old, seems in very good shape, apart from a few rafters - which are easily replaceable.

Walls are two brick wide which also seems very solid to me. Unfortunately the outer bricks  are almost all cracked since there is no finish on the outside walls and the bricks had been exposed to the sun the entire time. This doesn't bother me that much since they *should* be fine beneath the outermost surfaces.

What *does* bother me though, is the mortar they used. It is yellow-ish in color, which makes me think they were a bit off on the sand to cement ratio. This is further confirmed by a small secondary structure that we already demolished by hand, which was also made of bricks and had the exact same mortar as the house does. The bricks were extremely easy to remove, almost as if they were only held in place by their own weight.

The region is rather pleasant, we rarely get any storms with super high wind speeds, maybe a few times during summer, if at all. It is not a seismic zone, we get feelable earthquakes once every few years.

Overall the house gives the feeling that they used the best materials they could find at the time and they did not spare them, which makes me want to keep the house and just renovate it.

How dangerous is this mortar thing?

I don't currently have pictures, but I'm attaching a picture of a similar house I found on the web just for reference.

[image]

Comment: I would get local expert,building inspector/structural engineer, to see about the safety.  If too much mortar as been lost, then the walls might just be standing by luck.  Wood does not go bad/get weak with age, it can get rot or insect damage, and 30 years abandon might be enough for rot/insects to develop.

Comment: You really need eyes on site. They’ll ask about how good a job the roof was doing in the prior years. They’ll think about electrical. They’ll understand the floor system.

Answer (score 5):

If the roof kept the wood dry, that should be fine, barring other wood problems like termites, beetles, or carpenter ants.

As for the mortar, it's fairly standard brick wall maintenance to rake out 1/3-1/2 a brick deep and repoint (put in new mortar) when the mortar gets old and crumbly, so do that.

Past that point it's very hard to speculate with only a non-detailed picture of "not the actual house in question." For example: I would not consider bricks cracking "due to exposure to the sun" to even be a thing, frankly. Bricks are fired in kilns at thousands of degrees, so a bit of solar heating should have no effect, even it if managed to get to a few hundred degrees (unlikely.) Many brick buildings have the bricks exposed to the sun, without cracking, so probably there's something else going on.

Bricks cracking due to freeze-thaw cycles is a thing, in areas where it freezes, if they get wet and were poorly fired so they absorb moisture. They can also crack due to insufficient support. The wording of your question implies that you think they are only cracked on the surface, which would not be a big deal, if true. That would also probably be from the firing process, not the sun. If they are cracked right through, and it's "almost all of them" that would be a big deal indeed.